# Communication between spring boot dockerized apps

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

I new using spring boot and docker and I faced a problem running the docker containers.
On debug mode, there is no problem on applications boot, but when I run them as a container, there is something wrong.
For example, I have my server config with all the yml files, also eureka properties. 
The config server boot perfectly, but not the eureka server, it must look for it`s configuration to the config server becouse of these:

```
uri: ${vcap.services.config-service.credentials.uri:http://127.0.0.1:8888}
```

In the eureka`s log I can found:

> Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8888/server-eureka/default":Connection refused;
>   nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

So I see that eureka can`t connect to the config server for a reason I can`t understund.
Maybe I miss something in my docker file.

Comment: Have you exposed port 8888 from container? From "https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/" When we passed the -P flag to the docker run command Docker mapped any ports exposed in our image to our host.

Comment: Yes, of course, I used docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -t server/server-config and I can access the properties through http://172.20.xx.xx:8888/env/

Comment: Maybe you need to bind to localhost instead of 172.20.xx.xx as mentioned here http://serverfault.com/questions/565294/why-does-a-docker-container-running-a-server-expose-port-to-the-outside-world-ev

Comment: I had the same result

Comment: Are you running containers on different VMs or same VM?

Comment: I running the containers on ubuntu machine and I loaded the images and start  the containers separately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89015/discussion-between-sameer-naik-and-rys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using docker linked containers you'll have to use only the public ip addresses. Docker will assign every running container an own ip address which is per default not accessible. Only when you start to expose ports there will be an entry to iptables that is linking the hosts public ip address and given port to the internal used port and (dynamically assigned) ip address of the docker container. This is also why 127.0.0.1 does not work cause it would look into the containers local context but tgere the service is not running.

Comment: You are right! I change the value with the machine ip and it works.